# How to display record from database to display in tpl file, based on id_customer (prestashop 1.6)

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I just learned smarty and php, I created a new cms page in prestashop, I want to display data from the database precisely the **customer** table, I have successfully displayed the data, by adding this script in the **cmsController.php** file at **function initContent()**

```
 $this->context->smarty->assign(array('rows' => 
 Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `pspl_customer`')));
```

and here code on **cms.tpl** (id cms is 23, this only display for cms with that id)

```
{if $cms->id==23}
        {if isset($rows)}
            {foreach $rows as $row}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{$row.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            {/foreach}
        {/if}
    {/if}
```

but it's display all record like this :
[This is the result that is displayed on the cms page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKQYV.png)

THE QUESTION IS : how do I display data from a database based on id_customer (precisely the customer that is logged in), I don't want all records to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to pass in parameter the customer id, which is present in your cookies. As you will only have the necessary information on a client

Regards